# Playing Audio Files with spaces in filename

Tags: c#, filenames

is there any possibility to play audio-files with spaces in their names?

For instance: `Calvin Harris - Summer.mp3`

I want to open that file in the Windows Media Player/VLC Media Player and then the error log in the VLC shows: "Bad File descriptor in C:\..Project\Release\Calvin"
Problem: The spaces!

`CalvinHarris-Summer.mp3` can be opened without problems.

How could I solve that problem without renaming the audiofiles?

I'm starting the audiofile and the player with a `Process.Start`

Comment: Please post the code you're using to start the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the file name as an argument to the process with quotes around it, this should work for both VLC/WMP when there are blanks in the file name.

For example.

```
string fileIn = @"c:\Wherever\Calvin Harris - Summer.mp3";        

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\"", fileIn),
    FileName = VLC_EXE_PATH
};

Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: It works!
thank you very much for helping me out!